# Using fminsearch to solve an equation

Tags: matlab, equation-solving, fminsearch

```
(vgb-phy_s)^2=G^2*phy_t*((exp(-x)+x-1)+exp(-(2*phi_b/phi_t))*(exp(x)-x-1))
```

where

```
x=phy_s/phy_t
phy_t=0.0288; % phy_t=k*T/q; (k=1.3806503*10^-23, T=300 K, q=1.6*10^-19)
phy_b=0.5267; % phy_b=phy_t*ln(Na/ni)
G=(sqrt(2*q*es*Na)/cox);
```

Here I need to plot `phy_s` for different values of `vgb`.

I tried many ways but since I'm new to matlab I'm on my learning process, I'm not able to find a proper solution.

Few people suggested me to use `fminsearch` but its quite confusing and I'm getting lot of errors.

Comment: You are trying to graph something of the form `(x-y)^2 = k`; you can get an expression for `y` in terms of `x` with some trivial algebra...

Comment: Well, Thank you. But can fminsearch command be used for the above mentioned equation?

Comment: Your equation is incorrect: you have `[` but not `]`. Further, MATLAB uses `[` and `]` for concatenation and matrices, not for order of operations. And in MATLAB `2phi_b` is not a valid expression. You must use `2*phi_b`. Please edit you question and fix these incorrect expressions so that it becomes clear what is the equation or equation group that you are attempting to solve.

Comment: @nrz: I don't think this is meant to be Matlab syntax...

Answer (score 0):

`fminsearch` is a function for finding a minimum of a function, not for finding a solution of an equation. Further, here you don't have one equation but an equation group of at least 5 equations. You can use `solve` to solve equations and equation groups. However, an equation group of the following equations 1-5 does not have explicit solution. Another issue is that the constant values you propose seem to be imprecise values, and if you have more than one rounded or otherwise imprecise value, you can not find a solution even if the equation group was solvable (however, **this equation group does not have [an explicit] solution)**).

So, I'll show the steps to solve this but there seems to be something wrong with this equation group, even if the [probably imprecise] constant definitions (`phy_t=0.0288; phy_t=k*T/q; (k=1.3806503*10^-23; T=300; q=1.6*10^-19`; phy_b=0.5267;`) were left out.

Equations (without constant definitions):

```
1. (vgb-phy_s)^2 = G^2*phy_t*((exp(-x)+x-1)+exp(-(2*phi_b/phi_t))*(exp(x)-x-1))
2. x = phy_s/phy_t
3. phy_t = k*T/q
4. phy_b=phy_t*ln(Na/ni)
5. G=(sqrt(2*q*es*Na)/cox)
```

To solve eg. equation group of equations 1, 2 & 3:

```
Solution = solve('(vgb-phy_s)^2 = G^2*phy_t*((exp(-x)+x-1)+exp(-(2*phi_b/phi_t))*(exp(x)-x-1))', 'x = phy_s/phy_t', 'phy_t = k*T/q');

Solution.q
ans =
(T*k)/phy_t
(T*k)/phy_t

Solution.vgb
ans =
phy_s + (G*phy_t^(1/2)*(exp((2*phi_b)/phi_t) - exp(phy_s/phy_t) + exp((2*phy_s)/phy_t) - exp((2*phi_b)/phi_t)*exp(phy_s/phy_t) - (phy_s*exp(phy_s/phy_t))/phy_t + (phy_s*exp((2*phi_b)/phi_t)*exp(phy_s/phy_t))/phy_t)^(1/2))/(exp((2*phi_b)/phi_t)^(1/2)*exp(phy_s/phy_t)^(1/2))
phy_s - (G*phy_t^(1/2)*(exp((2*phi_b)/phi_t) - exp(phy_s/phy_t) + exp((2*phy_s)/phy_t) - exp((2*phi_b)/phi_t)*exp(phy_s/phy_t) - (phy_s*exp(phy_s/phy_t))/phy_t + (phy_s*exp((2*phi_b)/phi_t)*exp(phy_s/phy_t))/phy_t)^(1/2))/(exp((2*phi_b)/phi_t)^(1/2)*exp(phy_s/phy_t)^(1/2))

Solution.x
ans =
phy_s/phy_t
phy_s/phy_t
```

Do note that this solution is valid only for equation group of equations 1-3. For example equation group of equations 1, 2, 4 or 1, 2, 5 gives a different solution.

To solve the equation group of all 5 equations you could use this:

```
Solution = solve('(vgb-phy_s)^2 = G^2*phy_t*((exp(-x)+x-1)+exp(-(2*phi_b/phi_t))*(exp(x)-x-1))', 'x = phy_s/phy_t', 'phy_t = k*T/q', 'phy_b = phy_t*ln(Na/ni)', 'G = sqrt(2*q*es*Na)/cox');
```

However, there is no solution:

```
Warning: Explicit solution could not be found. 
In solve at 160 

Solution =
[ empty sym ]
```

So, I suggest that you try to find out what is wrong with your equations and then try `solve` again with corrected equations.